# chrome is injecting some stylesheet in popup ui which reduces the font size to 75%

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm designing the popup UI of the extension, default font size of browser is 16px and when I view the design outside the extension environment the default font size is 16px, but when I open the UI, chrome injects some stylesheet which reduces the font size to 75% which is equal to 12px.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

check my screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Solved the issue by setting ```font-size``` property's value to ```initial```. But I still want to know why this happens with browser?

Comment: It's a bug. Chrome adds this style to reuse the system font [since 2014](https://crbug.com/141703), but it calculates the font size wrong.